# How to install Ngrok 2.0 on linux subsystem on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, powershell, ngrok

I am trying to use Ngrok to create an introspected tunnel to localhost webhook development tool on my Linux subsystem (Powershell --> bash)

I try to install ngrok using the following:

```
sudo apt install ngrok-client
```

From what I understand the sudo command used installs ngrok v 1.6.
When I attempt to execute `ngrok 80` I get an error:

```
Invalid address server_addr 'ngrokd.ngrok.com:443'
```

I searched for this in another post and was informed that ngrok v. 1.6 is obsolete and in order to continue using ngrok would be to upgrade to 2.0

[Testing PayPal with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082548/testing-paypal-with-rails)

It's advised to download from the website http://ngrok.com, which is simple enough, but what is the correct way to download for linux subsystem use? Should I download for Linux and unzip? Or am I suppose to download for Windows?

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding anything

Comment: `sudo` does not install anything, it just gives elevated privileges to `apt` command that is responsible for installation of your package. As for you question, you should add more information about what Linux distribution you are using.

Comment: If you wonder `sudo` stands for `system user do`. Gives you privileges in the terminal to edit directories outside your home directory `/home/<username/`, otherwise the terminal commands can be executed only inside that directory. The fact is that `apt`, the application you are executing with `sudo` is creating files inside the root `/usr/bin` or `/usr/etc` ..not really sure which folder, but is under the root. So it needs privileges. Then `apt --help` so you see all the commands, one of this is `install`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use ubuntu since years, I trust the online instructions so either do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ngrok-client
```

or try to use [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703078/ngrok-installation-in-ubuntu-12-04#703082) and let me know if you have problems

the same instructions are included hear

```
$ unzip /path/to/ngrok.zip
```

`$` is just the sign from your terminal. You do not need to input `$`, but you need to open the terminal (ctrl+alt+t), run the unzip command to unzip the folder. 
You will find the folder under your downloads. So `/` is the root of your machine. You need to go inside your home folder which will be `/home` so you do `cd` (change directory) followed by that path

```
cd /home
```

then you do `ls` to list all the directories. You should see your profile with your name `username`. You should be able to get in the download folder with `cd <username>/Downloads` where `<username>` should be replaced with your personal folder name

At this point you are inside the `Downloads` directory. You can do an `ls` in your terminal, find the name of the file you downloaded (should be something like `ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip`) and run

```
unzip <file-name.zip>
```

where file name is the file you downloaded (something like `ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip`) or you can go back to the root directory and run

```
cd /
unzip /home/<username>/Downloads/<yourfile.zip>
```

> Read the [documentation](https://ngrok.com/docs/2) on how to use ngrok. Try it out by running it from the command line:

```
./ngrok help
```

Also I read from the documentation, that you can set up that address

There is some discussion online about this

[Testing PayPal with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082548/testing-paypal-with-rails#38096446)

I can help you more but I need your feedback

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package ngrok-client`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this from the official docs](https://ngrok.com/download).

`sudo tar xvzf ~/Downloads/ngrok-v3-stable-linux-amd64.tgz -C /usr/local/bin`